# How to solve an overdetermined system in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I would like to understand the reasons and find a way to avoid such behaviour of the `Solve` function in Mathematica 8.

```
Solve[x + y + z == 5 && y == 3 , {x, y}]
(* Out[1]= {{x -> 2 - z, y -> 3}} *)

Solve[x + y + z == 5 && y == 3 , {x}]
(* Out[2]= {} (why empty?) *)
```

I need to get an answer in the second case. Any suggestions on how to persuade the program to calculate an answer that is even simpler than the first?

Comment: These are under-determined systems not over-determined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, when the system of equations is overdetermined, you have an optimization problem and would therefore not expect `Solve` or `Reduce` to be the right tools because the equations are likely not solvable "exactly" but only in some "best possible" way.

You would then instead formulate the optimization problem in terms of a merit function that you attempt to extremize. For example, in a system of linear equations you would want to minimize the sum of squares of the error for each equation.

A simple implementation of this would be to use `Minimize`, and for more specialized solutions one can use `PseudoInverse` or `SingularValueDecomposition`. Since your example is very simple, I'll just try to illustrate how to treat it with `Minimize`:

```
Last@Minimize[{(x + y + z - 5)^2, y == 3}, {x}]
```

Here the `y == 3` is entered as a *constraint* whereas the other equation is converted to a squared "merit function" that has to be minimized. That last function would in general be a sum of several squares if you have more equations.

The result is a `Piecewise` expression of which we only need the part that actually satisfies `y == 3`:

> $ \left\{ x\to\begin{cases}
> 2-z & y=3\\
> \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}\right\}  $

An alternative would be:

```
Last@Minimize[{(x + y + z - 5)^2 + (y - 3)^2}, {x}]
```

> $ \{x \to 5 - y - z\}$

Answer (score 8):

You'll find the explanation in the [documentation page of `Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) under `Options -> MaxExtraConditions`, as well as under `Possible Issues` (in a less obvious form).

You can coerce `Solve` to give you a solution like this:

```
In[1]:= Solve[x + y + z == 5 && y == 3, {x}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
Out[1]= {{x -> ConditionalExpression[2 - z, y == 3]}}
```

The `MaxExtraConditions -> All` setting will allow `Solve` to generate extra conditions, and return a solution that is valid only under these special conditions.  By default `Solve` does not attempt this (usually computationally expensive) manoeuvre.  In your specific example it tells you that there are no solutions because there are indeed no solutions unless the very specific condition that `y` is equal to `3` is true.

I realize that this interpretation of the equations is counterintuitive at first.

The other solution is using `Reduce` which always attempts to generate all conditions that are necessary for the solution to be valid, even very special ones (e.g. that `a` must not be zero for `a x == 1` to have a solution).

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Reduce` in this case:

```
Reduce[x + y + z == 5 && y == 3, {x}]

(* output: y == 3 && x == 2 - z *)
```

`ToRules` will transform this expression to a list of rules, e.g.

```
ToRules[Reduce[x + y + z == 5 && y == 3, {x}]]

(* output: {y -> 3, x -> 2 - z} *)
```