# Solving Linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I am giving the following equations to *Mathematica* and it is giving any response .

The following is the command:-

```
Solve[
    {
           lam *p000 == mu*p100 , 
           mu*p001 == mu*p101 , 
           (lam + mu)*p010 == mu*(p001+p011+p110) , 
           2*mu*p011 == lam*p010 + mu*p111 , 
           (lam + mu)*p100 == mu*p011 + mu*p100 , 
           2*mu*p101 == mu*p011+mu*p111+lam*p100 , 
           (lam+2*mu)p110 == mu*p111+mu*p101 , 
           3*mu*p111 == lam*p110 , 
           p000+p001+p010+p011+p100+p101+p110+p111==1
    }
    , { p000,p001,p010,p011,p100,p101,p110,p111}
]
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/how-to-solve-an-overdetermined-system-in-mathematica

Comment: As shown in the answers, you have three options, (1) solve for the same number of variables as there are equations; (2) solve for fewer variables but include `MaxExtraConditions`; or (3) solve for fewer variables and specify variables to be eliminated (`Solve[eqns, solveVar, {elimVars}]`) (number of `solveVar` plus number of `elimVars` must equal number of equations). Note that `elimVars` must be a list even if there is only one variable.

Comment: I would to @Bob's nice summary a fourth option, the one that starts my answer: A result that indicates the (overdetermined) system is inconsistent is sometimes exactly the result I want, esp. if `Solve[sys, vars]` precisely represents the problem I want solved. The question for the user is, which of the options precisely represents the problem to be solved? (Example problem: Are three given lines concurrent or not?)

Comment: "...and it is giving any response" - do you mean "...and it is **not** giving any response"?

Comment: @BobHanlon Where can I find documentation for `{elimVars}`?  Thanks

Comment: @bbgodfrey - It was documented in earlier versions (e.g., [`v7`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html)) and apparently been kept around for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you list all the variables, it will give solution

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eqs = {lam p000 == mup100,
   mup001 == mup101,
   (lam + mu) p010 == mu (p001 + p011 + p110),
   2 mup011 == lamp010 + mup111,
   (lam + mu) p100 == mup011 + mup100,
   2 mup101 == mup011 + mup111 + lamp100,
   (lam + 2 mu) p110 == mup111 + mup101,
   3 mup111 == lamp110,
   p000 + p001 + p010 + p011 + p100 + p101 + p110 + p111 == 1
   };
vars = {p000, p001, p010, p011, p100, p101, p110, p111, mup100, 
   mup001, lam, mu, mup011, mup101, lamp010, mup111, lamp100, lamp110};
```

And now

```
Solve[eqs, vars]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you change vars to

```
vars = {p000, p001, p010, p011, p100, p101, p110, p111};
```

Then it is not happy, as you observed

```
Solve[eqs, vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice in your original input, I counted 9 equations, but you were solving for 8 variables. So system was overdetermined.

V 13.2

Answer (score 6):

`Solve` works for me:

```
sys = {lam*p000 == mu*p100, 
   mu*p001 == mu*p101, (lam + mu)*p010 == mu*(p001 + p011 + p110), 
   2*mu*p011 == lam*p010 + mu*p111, (lam + mu)*p100 == 
    mu*p011 + mu*p100, 
   2*mu*p101 == mu*p011 + mu*p111 + lam*p100, (lam + 2*mu) p110 == 
    mu*p111 + mu*p101, 3*mu*p111 == lam*p110, 
   p000 + p001 + p010 + p011 + p100 + p101 + p110 + p111 == 1};
Length[sys]
(*  9  *)

vars = {p000, p001, p010, p011, p100, p101, p110, p111};
Length[vars]
(*  8  *)

Solve[sys, vars]
(*  {}  *)
```

The result `{}` indicates that the system is (generically!) inconsistent, which is probably true.

You can use `Reduce` to find special relations among the parameters that yield solutions:

```
Reduce[sys, {lam, mu}, vars]
```

> ```
> (*
> (lam == 0 && mu == 0) ||
>  ((mu == 1/24 (lam - Sqrt[73] lam) || 
>    mu == 1/24 (lam + Sqrt[73] lam)) && lam != 0) ||
>  lam == 0 || 
>  mu == 0
> *)
> ```

Examples:

```
Solve[Append[sys, lam == 0], vars, {lam}]
```

> ```
> (*
> {{p000 -> 1, p001 -> 0, p010 -> 0, p011 -> 0, p100 -> 0, p101 -> 0, 
>   p110 -> 0, p111 -> 0}}
> *)
> ```

```
Solve[Append[sys, mu == 1/24 (lam - Sqrt[73] lam)], vars, {mu}]
```

> ```
> (*
> {{p000 -> (-1937 + 245 Sqrt[73])/(-65717 + 7433 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p001 -> (72 (-60395 + 7079 Sqrt[73]))/(-19534373 + 2289833 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p010 -> (36 (-73789 + 8737 Sqrt[73]))/(-19534373 + 2289833 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p011 -> (144 (-83 + 11 Sqrt[73]))/(-65717 + 7433 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p100 -> (12 (-443 + 47 Sqrt[73]))/(-65717 + 7433 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p101 -> (72 (-60395 + 7079 Sqrt[73]))/(-19534373 + 2289833 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p110 -> (36 (-33607 + 3763 Sqrt[73]))/(-19534373 + 2289833 Sqrt[73]), 
>   p111 -> (144 (-6697 + 829 Sqrt[73]))/(-19534373 + 2289833 Sqrt[73])}}
> *)
> ```

This yields a parametrized space of solutions:

```
Solve[Append[sys, mu == 0], vars, {mu}]
```

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
>
> ```
> (*
> {{p000 -> 0, 
>   p001 -> 1 - p011 - p101 - p111,
>   p010 -> 0, p100 -> 0 p110 -> 0}}
> *)
> ```

---

*Update:*

Forgot the above is built into `Solve`, more or less.  Use `MaxExtraConditions`:

```
Solve[sys, vars, MaxExtraConditions -> 10]
```

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
>
> [image]