# Solve[] does not return the solution to an easy system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations:

```
gl1 = b == a - 1;
gl2 = b == 3;
Solve[{gl1, gl2}, {a}]
```

The solution set provided by Mathematica is empty {} - even though a -> 4 would be the correct solution.

I just reset the kernel, so I made sure that none of the variables used were already defined elsewhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards
Jan

Comment: `Solve[{gl1, gl2}, {a}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]`

Comment: Another 2 duplicates: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7668/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6232/1871

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for:

```
gl1 = b == a - 1;
gl2 = b == 3;

Simplify[gl1, gl2]
```

or

```
Eliminate[{gl1, gl2}, b]
```

> a == 4

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
gl1 = b == a - 1;
gl2 = b == 3;
Solve[{gl1, gl2}, {a, b}]
```

> {{a -> 4, b -> 3}}

Comment: Do I need to include all the variables of my equations in the Solve function? Why isn't it working without the 'b'?

Comment: I think, gl1 and gl2 are two equations.